# Find the right most value Then exclude that value and find the next right most value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The table inserted below is cleaned data so dont worry about symbols or the numbers not making sense.
I am trying to grab the right most value, the credit column, and put it in a different output column and then grab the number on the inside of that, the debit column, and move it to a column to the left of the new credit column.

[Example of what columns look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvkCY.png)

So I am trying to either delete any form of text or strings in that range or I am trying to grab the rightmost value and then move it and then grab the right most value again and move it to the left side of the new column. I thought of doing this in grabbing the right most cell with a value and then copying it to a different cell and then clearing the contents and just looping through each cell doing (using VBA),

```
For Each xyz in Range("A1:G200") ...
```

or by deleting all of the text/strings and then grabbing the last cell in each row and then doing it by adding a -1 to grab the inside value.

Both ways I am having issues with looking for a general way to find text vs everything I have looked for only mentions specific text.

Any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

XFD is the right most cell in excel as of 2023. You can find your right most last populated cell by doing

```
set rRightMost = range("XFD" & lRow).end(xlToLeft)
```

lRow being the row you're interested in. Then, for the next right most last populated cell, you could:

```
set rRightMost = rRightMost.end(xlToLeft)
```

And voilá.